# log exception using logger in watir for any time a test fails

Tags: ruby, watir

I have tried many variations to try and access the checkbox. As you can see from this example: the ID is a guid so that is not going to be valuable. If you have a solution please help. Thanks.:

`browser.checkbox(:id, "05ae82c2-5725-4ed7-926e-01be3165bfa2").set`

I thought something like:

```
browser.checkbox(:label, "Ven_Q8").set
```

would work however the console showed this error:

```
`assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:label=>"Ven_Q8", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"checkbox"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

<div class="form-box">
<div class="form-body clearfix">
<form class="validate form-horizontal" method="post"
<div class="form-content">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Associated</label>
<div class="col-sm-4 list-height">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-replace neon-cb-replacement checked">
    <label>
    <label class="cb-wrapper">
    <input id="2ebb65b6-1048-4b0e-acf6-88b128a1e26b" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="2ebb65b6-1048-4b0e-acf6-88b128a1e26b" name="VendorOptions">
    <div class="checked"></div>
    </label>
    <label>Ven_Q8</label>
    </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`browser.checkbox(:label, "Ven_Q8").set` throws an `unable to locate element` error because `<input id="2ebb65b6-1048-4b0e-acf6-88b128a1e26b" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="2ebb65b6-1048-4b0e-acf6-88b128a1e26b" name="VendorOptions">` doesn't have a label attribute.

To check the checkbox, I'd suggest using the `name` attribute to locate the `<input>`:

```
b.checkbox(name: "VendorOptions").set
```